# Fully Automatic OS-Installation in VMs

Tags: automation, operating-system, installer

I must often install debian in virtual machines in the workstations I am working on and try to automate this.

I do not want to store and reuse preinstalled vms due to these disadvantages:

- I would also must to install it 12 times for the 12 usecases I have
- I would also must to often run a script which starts these 12 vms to update them.
- I would have a large disk-storage-requirement
- all vms of a usecase have the same name which is not desired sometimes

So I really think I should install a vm just in time when I need it.
Every time when I install debian in a vm I must set several common things during the installation of the os, for example:

- language/region of the os
- keyboard-layout
- http-proxy
- partitioning
- ...

In most of the cases these settings are the same. This is why I want to automate it. For these most cases I am looking for a cli-tool which can read the common settings from a config-file (for example: one config-file for each of the 12 usecases with the common-configurations for this usecase) so that I can write a script which passes the required parameter, e. g.

- the image-file which contains the os which should be installed
- the name of the vm
- the path to the configuration file with the common settings like keyboard-layout etc.
- maybe the root-pasword, but this is not required in my case

to the tool and then installs the virtualmachine.

I am currently using Windows/VMWare workstation but it would be ok for me to use Linux/Virtualbox/KVM/etc for this purpose.

Is there any software for this purpose?